# Chrome resets the textarea scroll bar (scrollTop) when focus is called

Tags: google-chrome, focus, textarea, scroll

Chrome (7.0.517.41 beta) (sometimes?) resets a textarea's scroll bar (`scrollTop`) when you call `focus`.  Does anyone know if this behavior is deliberate, a known bug, or neither?

It seems quite unintuitive; Firefox keeps it the same.  A simple example is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="text" rows="35" cols="160">
Long filler text here
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
var t = document.getElementById("text");
t.blur();
t.scrollTop = 500;
console.log("Before focus: " + t.scrollTop);
t.focus();
console.log("After focus: " + t.scrollTop);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could this be related to the position of the cursor in the textarea?

Comment: File a bug? http://crbug.com/

Comment: @Paul, thanks for reminding me.  Still present in 11.0.672.2, so I filed it as [issue 75072](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75072).

Comment: This happens in Safari as well, and seems to still be a problem in WebKit as of this morning. I've updated the Chromium bug you filed, and filed http://webk.it/68322 to ensure someone on the WebKit team sees it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike, thanks for following up!

Comment: @MikeWest, it got closed as a duplicate incorrectly.  Someone else and I commented to try to get it reopened, but nothing changed.